# Microformats and foreign languages

Tags: microformats

In the past when I decided to mark up microformats (pretty new to them) in english websites it would be like this:

```
<span class="tel">
  <span class="type">Home</span>:
  <span class="value">1234567</span>
</span>
```

However, when it comes to foreign languages I'm not sure if I can just do this:

```
<span class="tel">
  <span class="type">Home Phone in Chinese</span>:
  <span class="value">1234567</span>
</span>
```

or must I do this (or something else):

```
<span class="tel">
  <span class="type" style="text-indent:-9999em;">Home</span>Home Phone text in Chinese:
  <span class="value">1234567</span>
</span>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the microformats.org site is down right now, but when it comes back up, you'll see a solution to this here:

http://microformats.org/wiki/value-class-pattern

It looks like this:

```
<span class="tel">
  <span class="type"><span class="value-title" title="home"> </span>Home Phone in Chinese</span>:
  <span class="value">1234567</span>
</span>
```

Basically, you hide the machine-readable type in a title field when it doesn't match your human-readable type (either because of language or just different terminology). Note that the space in the value-title span is important to prevent some tools from ignoring the element when it's empty.